# How to remove (make invisible) EditText's cursor thumb?

Tags: android, xamarin

How to remove (make invisible) EditText's cursor thumb and make cursor position unchangeable?

Comment: can you explore your problem clearly?

Comment: What is unclear? I have an `EditText` and I don't know how to set cursor thumb invisible. There isn't really anything more to it than that ;) Sometimes short question **is** a clear question.

Comment: see,there is something else that's why your problem was not solved...try to ask question with full detailed manner like what you have tried etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the xml attribute `android:cursorVisible="false"` and add this `<requestFocus />` in **edittext** before closing. or the java function `editext.setCursorVisible(false)`.or try this xml attribute `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"`

Comment: you still can select text and it makes thumbs visible

Answer (score 0):

To make the cursor invisible and to make the cursor position fixed (let's say to position 3, i.e after adding 2 characters the cursor wont move) just add this line to your `EditText` xml:

```
//any 2 characters in text
<EditText ...
    ...
    android:text="12"
    android:cursorVisible="false" />
```

and in java do this:

```
yourEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            yourEditText.setSelection(yourEditText.getText().length());
        }
    });
```